# Why doesn't my GLB export have transparency?

Tags: materials, export, transparency

I'm working with a character that has translucent parts. I'm trying to export the final result as a GLB.

Typically the solution is to make parts of the image texture translucent and set the material's blend mode to alpha clip. However, this isn't the case in my scenario:

[image: Blend mode settings set to alpha clip.]

[image: The model with an opaque helmet.]

Instead, alpha hashed gives me the results I'm looking for:

[image: Blend mode settings set to alpha hashed.]

[image: The model with a translucent helmet.]

I'm not sure why this is, as I've always used alpha clip when it comes to transparent textures.

When I try to export the model as a GLB with the blend mode set to alpha hashed, the normals appear flipped, and the character's eyes appear to be always in front:

[image: The exported GLB, appearing to have flipped normals.]

...And when I export it with the blend mode set to alpha clip, the helmet is completely opaque:

[image: The exported GLB, with an opaque helmet.]

Why is this? How can I get the GLB export to look like the blend file set to alpha hashed?

You can find the project files [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lQnNAcA9XCF2AwWG4NuhwtDyEm-nVfcX/view?usp=sharing)! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution! I just had to put the transparent bits on a separate material.

I cloned the original material, changed the blend mode to "Alpha Hashed" on the new material, and set the blend mode to "Alpha Clip" on the original material.

Here's the final result:

[image: The final GLB export in 3D Viewer.]